# Get single ScrollableResults row

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to extract count(*) matching certain predicates. Every time I use `createSQLQuery`, I find myself having to write the code along the lines of,

```
// skipped code
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select count(*) from A where id=1");
Scrollable results = q.scroll();

while ( results.next() )
{
    Object[] row = Object[] results.get();
    // Assign it
    String str = row[0];
    //set and persist
}
```

I have many such queries unioned over a single transaction. How do I get single result here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method instead:

```
Object[] row = (Object[]) query.uniqueResult();
```

If the query returns more than one result, this method will throw an exception

EDIT:

On top of that, you could use a `ResultTransformer` to convert the `Object[]` into an `Integer`. This would remove the need to get the result array and then extract it's first entry. See this [example](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/hibernate/hibernate-query-language/custom-result-transformer.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks! By the way, am I mistaken to think that the object not be arrayed?